# Converting DeepLab to TensorFlow Lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert DeepLab trained on the Cityscapes dataset from here to TFLite. From viewing the frozen graph in Netron, the input and output tensors both are of type uint8. I was able to use the default DeepLab model provided for the TFLite GPU delegate, which had float32 input and output tensors. I didn't think the model was supposed to be quantized, so when trying the following code without the commented lines, I got this error:

```
F tensorflow/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:2241] Check failed: array.data_type == array.final_data_type Array "ImageTensor" has mis-matching actual and final data types (data_type=uint8, final_data_type=float).
```

After this, I found that I should try to quantize the model. I inserted the commented lines to use uint8 instead of float32, but I got this error, which seems like an unsupported op.

```
F ./tensorflow/lite/toco/toco_tooling.h:38] Check failed: s.ok() Unimplemented: this graph contains anoperator of type Cast for which the quantized form is not yet implemented. Sorry, and patches welcome (that's a relatively fun patch to write, mostly providing the actual quantized arithmetic code for this op).
```

Is it right to use the quantized script? The off-the-shelf TFLite DeepLab model provided uses float32. Thanks!